# What format is this template string/formula field in?

Tags: string, templates, format, formula, hellosign-api

I am building an integration for a client with the HelloWorks API. This is a service that allows you to create user-fillable PDF forms.

It appears that their product supports formatted/template strings/formula fields as outputs to the PDF files, as when
I create a Date field, it creates an output field with the following data:

```
#{format(:date, @field_XXXXX, "{0M}/{0D}/{YYYY}")}
```

However, I cannot find any kind of documentation as to what is the format of this template string/formula field.

Comment: I'm a HelloSign API support engineer and happy to help. For future reference, documentation for the HelloWorks API [can be found here](https://docs.helloworks.com/reference#getting-started) However, the documentation does not contain information on format that you're inquiring about. Can you clarify where you're seeing the output field you're referencing? Also, any additional information you can provide on your use case should help get this sorted out for you.

Comment: @erosiec thank you for your response. When I create a date field, the corresponding output field on the PDF looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/qn7eJls - I am trying to find a way to (a) have a date field with today's date which is NOT editable by the user and (b) have currency fields output in $XX,XXX format.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for an answer for this, this is what HelloWorks support team has to say.

> As for documentation for the format, we do not have any documentation for that at this time and the ability to make those edits are going to be depreciated in the future as our product team wants to bring those capabilities to the portal without custom edits.